# CSS image slider with fade in

Tags: css, animation, slider, slideshow, fadein

I have been trying to create a simple image slider showcasing four images for a website. I have managed to create the slideshow, however the transition between each images is really fast and I want a bit of a fade in effect so that it's smoother. A lot of the questions on here already suggest using jQuery but I am trying to do it with just CSS. I've also explored the animate.css but couldn't get it to work. Appreciate any/all help given. Thanks :)

Heres the code so far:

HTML

```
   <div class="slider">
      <div class="feature">
      </div>
      <div class="overlay">

      </div>
   </div>
```

and the CSS

```
.feature {
   animation: slide 3s;

}

.slider {
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
   width: 100%;
   height: 80vh;
   animation: slide 10s infinite;
}

.overlay {
   color: #fff;
   width: 100%;
   height: 80vh;
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}



@keyframes slide {
   0%{
      background-image: url(../resources/feature/Feature1.jpg);
   }

   25%{
      background-image: url(../resources/feature/Feature1.jpg);
   }

   25.1%{
      background-image: url(../resources/feature/Feature2.jpg);
   }

   50%{
      background-image: url(../resources/feature/Feature2.jpg);
   }
   50.01%{
      background-image: url(../resources/feature/Feature3.jpg);
   }

   75%{
      background-image: url(../resources/feature/Feature3.jpg);
   }

   75.01%{
      background-image: url(../resources/feature/Feature4.jpg);
   }

   100%{
      background-image: url(../resources/feature/Feature4.jpg);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the `opacity` and `transition` of the "sliders" to get the effect.

```css
.feature {

}

.slider {
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
   width: 100%;
   height: 80vh;
   transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
   animation: slide 10s infinite;
}

.overlay {
   color: #fff;
   width: 100%;
   height: 80vh;
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
   transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}



@keyframes slide {
   0%{
      opacity: 0;
      background-color: red;
   }

   20%{
   opacity: 1;
      background-color: red;
   }
   25%{
   opacity: 0;
      background-color: red;
   }
   25.1%{
   opacity: 0;
      background-color: blue;
   }

   45%{
   opacity: 1;
      background-color: blue;
   }
   50%{
   opacity: 0;
      background-color: blue;
   }
   50.01%{
   opacity: 0;
      background-color: yellow;
   }

   70%{
   opacity: 1;
      background-color: yellow;
   }
   75%{
   opacity: 0;
      background-color: yellow;
   }

   75.01%{
   opacity: 0;
      background-color: green;
   }

   95%{
   opacity: 1;
      background-color: green;
   }
   100%{
   opacity: 0;
      background-color: green;
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
      <div class="feature">
      </div>
      <div class="overlay">

      </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Perfect! I was trying to add the transition in but i was doing it wrong/separately. Is it possible to change the transition color to black and/or just overlay the next image so its smoother? (I Hope I'm making sense :D)

Comment: Yes it is possible, but I would use a solution with JavaScript which you can easily increase or decrease images quantity as well the time and transitions type. So to achieve on CSS keyframes the logic would be to set different animation times for .feature and .overlay, like .feature starts and in 3 secs get opacity:0, then .overlay starts on 2.5 secs getting the opacity:1 at 3secs and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Just change the line

```css
animation: slide 10s infinite;
```

to

```css
animation: slide 20s infinite;
```

and it would give some time for transition.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to manege  animation Opacity and no any other way to create this slider will show & transition.

```
     @keyframes slide {
   0%{
      background-image: url(https://image.flaticon.com/sprites/new_packs/178146-business-strategy.png);

   }
   48%{ opacity:0;
   }
   50%{
      opacity:1;
      background-image: url(https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51TxXo0RLgL.png);

   }
   97%{ opacity:1;
   98%{ opacity:0;
    100%{
      opacity:1;
      background-image: url(https://image.flaticon.com/sprites/new_packs/178146-business-strategy.png);

   }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m4tsudc7/21/